# How do I Use Bootstrap PopOver and jQuery to Remove an Item

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap popover which shows a 'Remove' button action:

```
<a href="#" class='dd' rel="popover" data-content="<a href='#' class='removeNote btn' data-id='{{$note->id}}'  >Remove</a>" data-original-title="Remove Note?"><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>
```

I want the remove action "removeNote" to invoke the remove jQuery code block, but it is not. If I remove the popover code, it works fine. Any ideas?

```
$(".removeNote").click(function() {

var id = $(this).data("id");

$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/note/' + id,
    data: {
        'id': id
    },
    success: function(msg) {

     $(".note" + id ).fadeOut(500);
     $(".poster" + id ).fadeOut(500);
 }
 });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you replace double quotes with simple quotes and vice versa would work. Like this:

```
<a href="#" class='dd' rel="popover" data-content='<a href="#" class="removeNote btn" data-id="{{$note->id}}">Remove</a>' data-original-title="Remove Note?"><i class='icon-remove'></i></a>
```

But I would put my link into the markup and not into some data tag. This is how it could work:

Popover JS Code:

```
$("[data-rel=popover]").popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
      return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

Popover HTML Markup:

```
<a href="#" id="popover">the popover link</a>
<!-- popover content: Header and content -->
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">Remove Note</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
<a href="#" class="removeNote btn" data-id="{{$note->id}}">Remove</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What you have makes sense. It is still not firing the 'removeNote' block. There is nothing here that stands out as an issue except for the logic flow within jQuery.

Comment: Changing the double quotes doesn't work either? and, by the way, what does "{{$note->id}}" stands for?

Comment: {{$note->id}} is Blade syntax (template engine). Laravel 4 is what I am using. Alas, quotes did not help. I am baffled...it must be how Bootstrap handles the popover. I am going to try and put it into the 'removeNote' code block and see what I can do there.

Comment: No success. I am trying to use Bootbox next. I moved on to other fish. But will update this post once I find a solution!